# Why won't Linux execute a bash script that has execution permission from Java?

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

There are numerous questions that look similar to this , but none of them seem to be exactly the same and all their solutions have not worked for me, so here it goes...

I have a Java program that tries to auto-update itself. It works like this:

- on startup, a bash script checks for the presence of a zip file in a certain location.
- if it exists, instead of running the "real" main class, it runs the updater Java class.
- this class will unpack the zip in a temp location, then start itself again in a separate process, from that temp location.
- once the new process starts, the old one exits.
- the new process tries to unpack the zip again, into the previous location (which now has nothing running so can be replaced).
- on success, it deletes the zip file and runs the original bash script again.

If everything worked, the bash script now would just start the Java main class.

Everything in this list actually works, except for the very last step when I try to execute the bash script at the end.

The bash file permissions look like this (both before and after I run the auto-updater):

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

As far as I can see, there should be no permissions issue running this file (and in fact, I can run it manually immediately after the process crashes).

Here's the error I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/xxx/build/image/bin/run": error=13, Permission denied
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at my_mod/my.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

I wrote a "process bomb" that works similarly, but that worked:

- start by running a bash script that launches a main class
- the main class uses the following code to start the bash script again:

  ```
  // DO NOT RUN THIS AT HOME!
  // IT WILL START LOTS OF PROCESSES INFINITELY
  // if you do want to try it, have "killall -9 java" ready!
  try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec( path )
      System.exit(0);
  } catch ( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

So I think that this is not some kind of Linux protection against process bombs like this.

But I am completely puzzled why Linux is still denying access to running that bash script after the update.

My OS is Ubuntu 19.

How can I find out why it's denying access, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you can try to check the attribute and ownership of the file, check if there is any attribute assign to the bash 'lsattr <file_name>'

Comment: This command prints `--------------e-----`.

Comment: Disable the 'e' using "chattr -e <file_name>" and try..

Comment: I can run the file from the terminal, it just won't work when Java tries to do it immediately after creating it... so to try this I would need to change attributes from Java, but it seems that if attributes were a problem, I couldn't run it even from the terminal, no?

Comment: yes logically it should not be a problem, but sometimes file attribute can leads to uncertainty... however, seem you are stuck currently so maybe you can try it to disable the 'e', since normally file are not set with any attribute.. although there are no confirmation but if no option then we can give a try..

Comment: Could you share more code? There's no way to reproduce your issue right now. Also, beyond the issue at hand, your update process seems a little over-complicated, Why do you need so many different processes and a back-and-forth between bash and Java? If your updater is in Java, why do you need bash at all?

Comment: @Dici do you have experince writing a self-updater Java app? If you do, please share a simpler way. Bash is required because the launcher is written in bash and the distribution is self-contained, with the JRE included (hence the only other option would be to tell my users to run "myapp/bin/java <several JVM options> mymod/myclass`. I will create a simple GH repo with a reproducible project as it's too much code to post here.

Comment: @Renato no the only self-updating tools I have written were simple CLI Python tools and all I had was a bash script pulling from a remote repository (which updates the Python code as well as the list of dependencies), installs dependencies listed in the updated dependency file, and then executes the Python entry point. The feedback I gave above was just the impression that there was too much back-and-forth in the flow you've described.

Comment: @Renato - 1) Why did you decide to post a process bomb as your example?  Surely you could have thought of something safe for people to try?  2)  Surely you can write a program that tries to run a shell script in a few tens of lines of code?  Not a github repo's worth.

Comment: My guess is that this is being blocked by a MAC (mandatory access control) mechanism.  For example SE-Linux or AppArmor.  What Linux distro are you using?  Some have SE-Linux enabled by default.

Comment: @StephenC 1) it's the simplest possible example of what kind of thing I am doing. I agree it would be nice to post something that reproduces the problem but I haven't been able to do that. 2) the problem seems to be with starting a process from Java from the same bash script that started Java itself, from what I can tell, Thats' why I do not think bash alone would suffice. The reason the self-updater is in Java is so that I do not need to maintain also a bat version for Windows, I can show a progress bar, I can make it much more complex later, etc.

Comment: How large is the application? If it's small you could simply copy it to a different location and run the updater there. Also, you could completely decouple the updater from the application itself, that way you wouldn't need to start the adapter and the bash script twice. The simplest flow would be: start bash script, run updater from bash, run Java app from bash if update was successful

Comment: Most likely the file is still open from writing it.

Comment: I've just found out that the process cannot execute anything at all. Things that normally work, like `exec("jps")` are failing for the same reason within the spawned process, so it seems the process just starts in some kind of sandbox! The only difference from a normal process is that this process starts from a program that has just been unzipped, so I think the OS is using some kind of sandbox to run it.... will post an answer if this leads anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found out the root cause of the problem: it was due to file permissions, but **not with the file the error message mentions**!

The way I was unpacking the new application update was via writing a simple "unzipper" in Java with the following, basic implementation:

```
    try (var zip = new ZipInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(newVersionZipFile), 4096))) {
        var zipEntry = zip.getNextEntry();
        if (zipEntry == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Expected at least one entry in the zip file: " + newVersionZipFile);
        }
        var topEntryName = zipEntry.getName();
        zipEntry = zip.getNextEntry();
        while (zipEntry != null) {
            var file = fileFor(zipEntry, destinationDir, topEntryName);
            if (isDirectory(zipEntry)) {
                var ok = file.mkdir();
                if (!ok) throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create new directory: " + file);
            } else {
                Files.copy(zip, file.toPath());
            }
            zipEntry = zip.getNextEntry();
        }
    }
```

This actually works, mostly, but it has a big problem: it does not consider file permissions. I had noticed the problem and made everything in the `bin` directory executable after unzipping, but what I had not anticipated was that there more executable files in the minimal-JVM created by jlink. And because the application actually mostly worked, that made me think everything was fine!

Using the `tree` command, I looked at the directory tree after unzipping it with Linux's `unzip`, and with my custom Java unzip. I noticed that, with `unzip`, besides the files in the `bin` directory, the following files also had execution permission:

```
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  lib
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  classlist
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  javafx.properties
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  javafx-swt.jar
│   ├── [-rwxrwxr-x]  jexec
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  jrt-fs.jar
│   ├── [-rwxrwxr-x]  jspawnhelper
...
```

In contrast, the tree unzipped by the Java unzipper looked like this:

```
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  lib
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  classlist
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  javafx.properties
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  javafx-swt.jar
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  jexec
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  jrt-fs.jar
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  jspawnhelper
...
```

Noticed that two files are supposed to have execution permission: `jexec` and `jspawnhelper`, both of which have names that strongly suggest they have something to do with executing other processes :D

To test this hypothesis, I made the unzipper also change the permissions of these two files to executable, and now everything works as expected!

My challenge now turns to how to actually keep the file permissions of all files when unzipping it, and that's another rabbit hole as there is no standard way to get file permissions from a standard zip (which is why the Java API for zips does not have that feature). There are external libraries that mostly work, so I'll probably end up using one of them... but that's another topic.